# Getting stickynotes to stay always on top?

Tags: 11.04, notes, stickynotes

(just documenting this - self-answer to follow)

I am using the `stickynotes` applet in Ubuntu Natty for notes. I would occasionally like these notes to stay "always on top", but I cannot find a setting for anything like that (pic from [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-little-useful-sticky-notes-app-for-linux/)):

[image: stickynotes]

Is it at all possible to somehow force a `stickynotes` note to stay always on top?

Answer (score 4):

Yup, it is possible - got the answer thanks to this post: [Application started in shell automatically "always on top" / Desktop / Xfce Forums](http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6905); one can use `wmctrl` for that.

First, in terminal, use `wmctrl` to obtain a listing of currently active windows:

```
$ wmctrl -l
0x01a00003 -1 mypc Bottom Expanded Edge Panel
0x01a00036 -1 mypc Top Expanded Edge Panel
0x01200023 -1 mypc x-nautilus-desktop
0x042000e1  1 mypc Mozilla Firefox
0x03400024  0 mypc Terminal
0x032000f2 -1 mypc 2013-03-29
```

The "2013-03-29" is the title of my `stickynotes` note window; then one can just run this command, in order to force that particular note window to stay on top:

```
wmctrl -i -r 0x032000f2 -b toggle,above
```

Note the use of `-i` switch, to "*Interpret window arguments (<WIN>) as a numeric value rather than a string name for the window.*". Also, this *toggles* the "always on top" property for the window; so if you'd like to turn the "always on top" off - simply run the same above command again.

Note that if `stickynotes` is set up to "Put notes on all workspaces"; then the "always on top" setting will be valid for all workspaces (although you may have to click through other windows at first, to have the window "understand" it should be "always on top").